# Process audio input from a mobile microphone without saving it to a file

Tags: ios, xamarin, signal-processing, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I'm working on a mobile application that can perform basic analysis on audio input from the microphone in real time. However, the usual way to do it using the 'AVAudioRecorder` as shown in this [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/record_sound/) and the [API](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/AVFoundation.AVAudioSequencer/) requires you to save it to a file first.

Since the app is meant to stay on for a long time and be used multiple times a day, I want to avoid clutter the phone with many audio files or audio files that are too big.  However, I can't seem to find the way around it. Searching for solutions on the internet always lead to solutions of how to save an audio to a file, instead of avoiding saving to a file and work with some kind of buffer.

Any pointers would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the iOS Audio Unit and the Audio Queue APIs allow one to process short buffers of audio input in real-time without saving to a file.

You can also use a tap on the AVAudioEngine.  See Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVAEMixerSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks! Working hard on implementing AudioQueue in C# now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/dev/null` as path in the `AVAudioRecorder` instance. This way it will not save to a file, but just discard the data.

```
var url = NSUrl.FromString("/dev/null");
var recorder = new AVAudioRecorder(url, settings, out error);
```

Comment: Mm it's true but if we just toss away the data as soon as it's recorded ... then why record it in the first place?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. I.e. you can use this just to get average power or peak power from the microphone